# Updating Oxyplot graph in real time and separate from WPF form loading (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, oxyplot

I have just moved over from windows forms to WPF (c#) and am struggling coming to grips with OxyPlot, after making the switch from ZedGraphs. After hours of searching the internet and watching tutorials here i am...

I currently have a graph that's reading serial data and plotting the data over 10 seconds. I am also new to XAML so I appreciate your patience.

When I test the programme I am left waiting for 10 seconds whilst the graph takes all the data and then plots and opens the application. I am looking to manage opening the graph myself and not automatically on boot up. I also need to view the graph in real time instead of having to wait for all the data to be added and then be loaded at the end.

Thanks

```
<Window x:Class="Graph_test_5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Graph_test_5"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <oxy:PlotView x:Name="Graph1" Model="{Binding MyModel}"/>
    </Grid>
```

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
         SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort();
         public MainViewModel()
         {
             Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
             stopwatch.Start();

             myPort.BaudRate = 9600;
             myPort.PortName = "COM4";
             myPort.Open();
             MyModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Line" };
             var myModel = new LineSeries { };

             while (stopwatch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
             {

                 string Number = myPort.ReadLine();
                 double Num;
                 bool isNum = double.TryParse(Number, out Num); // Is the incomming serial data a number?
                 if (isNum) // If it is a number...
                 {
                     int IncommingInt = Convert.ToInt32(Number);
                     long x = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                     myModel.Points.Add(new DataPoint(x, IncommingInt));
                 }
             }
            MyModel.Series.Add(myModel);
         }

         public PlotModel MyModel { get; private set; }
     }
```

Comment: This is the same as under WinForms - you can't block the main thread for so long. How did you do it before?

Comment: Why don't you use the `DataReceived` event of SerialPort? Using stopwatch like that is quite icky.

Comment: @HenkHolterman using zed graphs I added all new data in a pairpointlist and then used that to update the axis. Zed graph also had a refresh  tool which allowed me to update it with the new data point after each serial read. It was also all part of my main thread which like you mentioned, blocked the main thread. This time I wanted to move into the world of classes to prevent this... I am self teaching at the moment so i'm sorry If i'm going about this the complete wrong way!

Comment: @HebeleHododo I will look into DataRecieved now, I was using stopwatch as the amount of data i require to plot is time critical and will be used to data log in the future for a set amount of time

Comment: Go for the Received event. And then make the Points.Add thread-safe using  Scheduler.Invoke().

Comment: @charley I assume you are reading sampled data. If so, you know the sample rate, so you can generate the x-axis (time) data and just use `DataReceived` event. This way, when you receive the first, let's say 100 data points, and your sampling time is 10 ms, you will have the data for the first second of your sample.